# How to reconnect consumer with twisted connection for pika?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, twisted, pika

I used pika twisted connection as a RabbitMQ consumer, and here is my code:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def run(connection):
    queue_name = 'aaa'
    channel = yield connection.channel()
    queue = yield channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, auto_delete=False, exclusive=False)
    yield channel.queue_bind(exchange='amq.direct',queue=queue_name,routing_key=queue_name)
    yield channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    queue_object, consumer_tag = yield channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name,no_ack=False)
    logger.info('[room server]start consume queue %s', queue_name)

    l = task.LoopingCall(read, queue_object)
    l.start(0.1)


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def read(queue_object):
    ch,method,properties,body = yield queue_object.get()
    try:
        data = json.loads(body)
        head_code = data['head_code']
        openid = data['openid']
        message_content = data['message_content']
        conn_id = -1
        try:
            conn_id = data['conn_id']
        except:
            pass
        message_dispatcher(head_code, openid, message_content, conn_id)
        yield ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    except ValueError as e:
        logger.error('[error!]error body %s' % body)
        yield ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(config.RABBITMQ_USERNAME, config.RABBITMQ_PASSWD)
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(credentials=credentials)
cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, twisted_connection.TwistedProtocolConnection, parameters)

def got_error(failure, d):
    logger.error(failure)
    d = cc.connectTCP(config.RABBITMQ_HOST, config.RABBITMQ_PORT)


def start():
    d = cc.connectTCP(config.RABBITMQ_HOST, config.RABBITMQ_PORT)
    d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
    d.addCallback(run)
    d.addErrback(got_error, d)
```

My problem is when the connection breaks, the re-connection process does not work:[image]

How to make re-connection work?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`TwistedProtocolConnection` docstring](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/adapters/twisted.html#pika.adapters.twisted_connection.TwistedProtocolConnection), an `on_close_callback` function can be supplied to handle connection termination. In this function, a [`reason_code` and `reason_text`](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/pika/connection.py#L2022) must be args. So create another on_close callback where you handle connection terminations and the reasons why it happened, then execute the necessary logic to connect to  RabbitMQ:

```
def connection_termination(reason_code, reason_text):
    """
    Log the reasons why the connection terminates and then reconnect
    """
    # put your connection code here
    # incrementally space out your reconnections, eg. 2 seconds, if fail, 5 seconds, if fail 10 seconds, etc...
```

Once you have that code in place, then your `ClientCreator` code should follow the example below:

```
cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, twisted_connection.TwistedProtocolConnection, parameters, connection_termination)
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to test this at the moment but it should work. You have most of the logic already, so I'll leave the rest for you as an exercise ;) Please comment if you have any issues and if you have a solution, please show the end result for others.

Comment: I tried your code but exception raised:in start
    d = cc.connectTCP(config.RABBITMQ_HOST, config.RABBITMQ_PORT)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 292, in connectTCP
    bindAddress=bindAddress)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 274, in _connect
    self.reactor, self.protocolClass(*self.args, **self.kwargs), d)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)